# Userspace Network Stack

Tags: kernel, ip, network-interface, tcpdump

I am writing a (very simple) userland IP network stack. For this purpose, I need to go "around" the OS network stack and obtain the raw Ethernet frames. The `tap` interface sounds like a way to go, but it does not seem to work for me. I created a `bridge` interface between the `wlan` and `tap` interfaces, but only few super-weird UDP packets seem to appear there (`tcpdump -i tap0 -e -vv` says so), even though the real `wlan` interface contains lots of other packets (again, `tcpdump` confirms).

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any other (better) way to go about the userspace network stack solution?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you cannot bridge wlan and lan/tap as they do not use the exactly same protocol. Bridging lan and tap should work fine.

Comment: Look up about  `netfilter_queue` ...

Answer (score 0):

You can't bridge wifi station-mode interfaces, it doesn't work. It does not matter what software stack you are using. This limitation applies to e.g. virtualisation.

This is not obvious, I'll try to explain it.

ieee802.11 packets (usually) have THREE addresses in them. These are the address of the access-point, the address of the sender and the address of the receiver. Note that the sender and receiver addresses are ethernet MAC addresses, which are shared between wired and wireless ethernet. Packets can flow between wireless "stations" and hosts on the wired network (aka "DS", distribution system), but cannot be further distributed from stations, because there aren't enough address fields in the packet to contain a station ID AND a destination address (they are the same field).

The result is, that you can bridge a "master mode" (access-point) interface, but you can't bridge a station-mode interface.

The solution is generally, to use routing instead of bridging, typically with NAT.